# How to test wether Service is up or not using Node Js

Tags: asp.net, node.js

I am doing the following code to test whether a service is up or not , but I am always getting error , can you please point me what I am doing wrong. The one I am trying to invoke is a dotnet webservice. I tried giving port also , But that also didn't work

```
var http = require('http');

     var options = {
     host: 'www.test.com/SomeService.svc'    
     };

 http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log('got response: ' + res.statusCode);
 }).on('error', function(err) {
 console.log('got error: ' + err.message);
 });
```

I am getting below error.

got error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`host` should be just the hostname... `www.test.com`.

The request path is not part of the hostname.  With recent versions of Node.js, you can just pass a string URL to the first parameter in `.get`.  No need for the options object if you have a URL.

```
http.get('http://www.test.com/SomeService.svc', function (res) {
```

Comment: I want to write a small utility in node which validates if all our services are up and running perfect , I will use this one. Thanks very much for your quick answer